# Istio local rate limiter using Envoy filter for a specific request path and source labels

Tags: istio, throttling, envoyproxy, rate-limiting, servicemesh

In a Service Mesh controlled by Istio, I would like to throttle the inbound traffic based on two conditions below:

- Request path
- Source Label (e.g., `app: an-app`)

Every document guided me to use `descriptors` but I cannot use it because the request does not contains proper header information for POST API such as `:path` or else.

Here is the configuration for current Envoy filter and it works fine for throttle all inbound traffics via 80 port but what I really want to do is using different bucket conditions for each API path and source labels.

Is there any reference for throttle the requests based on these criteria?

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: filter-my-api-local-ratelimit-svc
  namespace: myns
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      app: my-api
  configPatches:
    - applyTo: HTTP_FILTER
      match:
        context: SIDECAR_INBOUND
        listener:
          filterChain:
            filter:
              name: "envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager"
      patch:
        operation: INSERT_BEFORE
        value:
          name: envoy.filters.http.local_ratelimit
          typed_config:
            "@type": type.googleapis.com/udpa.type.v1.TypedStruct
            type_url: type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.local_ratelimit.v3.LocalRateLimit
            value:
              stat_prefix: http_local_rate_limiter
    - applyTo: HTTP_ROUTE
      match:
        context: SIDECAR_INBOUND
        routeConfiguration:
          vhost:
            name: "inbound|http|80"
            route:
              action: ANY
      patch:
        operation: MERGE
        value:
          typed_per_filter_config:
            envoy.filters.http.local_ratelimit:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/udpa.type.v1.TypedStruct
              type_url: type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.local_ratelimit.v3.LocalRateLimit
              value:
                stat_prefix: http_local_rate_limiter
                token_bucket:
                  max_tokens: 3
                  tokens_per_fill: 3
                  fill_interval: 60s
                filter_enabled:
                  runtime_key: local_rate_limit_enabled
                  default_value:
                    numerator: 100
                    denominator: HUNDRED
                filter_enforced:
                  runtime_key: local_rate_limit_enforced
                  default_value:
                    numerator: 100
                    denominator: HUNDRED
                response_headers_to_add:
                  - append: false
                    header:
                      key: x-local-rate-limit
                      value: 'true'
```

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes and Istio did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider? It is important to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak 

Here are the version informations: 
- `K8s : v1.17.2`
- `Istiod : v1.9.9`

We installed kubernetes via `Rancher` and installed Istio through the guide document below: 
https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/getting-started/

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak Here is the Envoy version used as istio-proxy : `.../1.17.1/Clean/RELEASE/BoringSSL`

Comment: You are using very old version Kubernetes and Istio. Could you update them?

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak 
Oh. I see. I'll try it.

Comment: Please let me know then.